# Regex capturing the first occurrence of every group in a recurring pattern

Tags: regex, capturing-group, negative-lookbehind

Suppose I have the following text:

```
Name: John Doe\tAddress: Street 123 ABC\tCity: MyCity
```

I have a regex (a bit more complex, but it boils down to this):

```
^(?:(?:(?:Name: (.+?))|(?:Address: (.+?))|(?:City: (.+?)))\t*)+$
```

which has three capturing groups, that can capture the values of Name, Address and City (if they occur in the text). A few more examples are here: https://regex101.com/r/37nemH/6. **EDIT** The ordering is not fixed beforehand, and it could also happen that the fields are *not* separated by `\t` characters.

Now this all works well, the only slight problem I have is when one field occurs twice in the same text, as can be seen in the last example I put on regex101:

```
Name: John Doe\tAddress: Street 123 ABC\tCity: MyCity\tAddress: Other Address
```

What I would want is for the second capturing group to match the *first* address, i.e. `Street 123 ABC`, and preferably to let the second occurrence be matched within the "City" group, i.e.

```
1: John Doe
2: Street 123 ABC
3: MyCity\tAddress: Other Address
```

Conceptually, I tried doing this with a negative lookbehind, e.g. replacing `(?:Address: (.+?))` with `(?:(?<!.*Address: )Address: (.+?))`, i.e. assuring that an `Address:` match was not proceded somewhere in the text by another `Address:` tag. But, negative lookbehind does not allow for arbitrary length, so this obviously would not work.

Can this be achieved using regex, and how?

Comment: Try matching and capturing the values consecutively, `^(.*?)Name:\s+(.*?)\s+Address:\s+(.*?)\s+(?:City:\s+(.*?)\s*)?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LyaZOj/1).

Comment: If the word order can be any and some or all the items can be missing, it is much easier to use 3 separate patterns to extract the bits you need.

Comment: Would this also work when the fields are not clearly separated? E.g. if the text is along the lines of `Name: John DoeAddress: Street 123 ABC`?

Comment: 1) [Name](https://regex101.com/r/37nemH/7), 2) [City](https://regex101.com/r/37nemH/8), 3) [Address](https://regex101.com/r/37nemH/9)

Comment: That works like a charm. Then I would imagine it would just be asking too much to have the match for City to be `MyCity\tAddress: Other Address` as I mentioned as preferable behaviour in the question, wouldn't it ;)

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. And I do not think it is easy. Try https://regex101.com/r/37nemH/12

Comment: Should I post any answer? Is that requirement to get the second Address into City important?

Comment: I would post your upvoted comment about the separate name, city and address patterns as answers, I've been helped by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the word order can be any and some or all the items can be missing, it is much easier to use 3 separate patterns to extract the bits you need.

*Name* ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKm7B0/1)):

```
^.*?Name:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:Name:|Address:|City:|$))
```

*City* ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKm7B0/2)):

```
^.*?City:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:Name:|Address:|City:|$))
```

*Address* ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKm7B0/3)):

```
^.*?Address:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:Name:|Address:|City:|$))
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `Address:` - a keyword to stop at and look for the expected match
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible...
- `(?=\s*(?:Name:|Address:|City:|$))` - up to but excluding 0 or more whitespaces followed with `Name:`, `Address:`, `City:` or end of string.

Answer (score 3):

For your stated problem, you may use this regex with a conditional construct:

```
^.*?(?:(?:Name: (.+?)|(Address: )(.+?)|City: ((?(2).*?Address: )*.+?))\t*)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/37nemH/13)

Your values are available in captured groups 1, 3, 4.

Capture group 2 is for literal label `"Address: "`.

Here, `(?(2).*?Address: )*` is a conditional construct that means if captured group 2 is present then in group 4 match text till next `Address:` is found (0 or more matches of this).

For the text `Name: John Doe    Address: Street 123 ABC         City: MyCity    Address: Second address`, it will have following matches:

```
Group 1.    169-177 `John Doe`
Group 2.    178-187 `Address: `
Group 3.    187-201 `Street 123 ABC`
Group 4.    210-240 `MyCity Address: Second address`
```

Comment: I like your approach. I've accepted the other answer because this one would be a bit difficult to generalize (say: not only the address field can appear twice, but any field), but it's good to see there is a solution to also get my preferred behaviour

Comment: Thanks. That is your prerogative but Wiktor's regex won't capture `Address: Second address` in `City` capture group.